# Regarding Hard Link

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems

Can somebody please explain me why the kernel doesn't allow us to make a hard link to a directory. Whether it is because it breaks the rule of directed acyclic graph structure of the file-system or it is because of some other reason. What other complications come if it allows that?

Comment: Sounds like it. There are a few details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link#Limitations_of_hard_links).

Comment: This isn't a kernel question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Back in the days of 7th Edition (or Version 7) UNIX, there were no system calls `mkdir(2)` and `rmdir(2)`.  The `mkdir(1)` program was SUID root, and used the `mknod(2)` system call to create the directory and the `link(2)` system call to make the entries for `.` and `..` in the new directory.  The `link(2)` system call only allowed root to do that.  Consequently, way back then (circa 1978), it was possible for the superuser to create links to directories, but only the superuser was permitted to do so to ensure that there were no problems with cycles or other missing links.  There were diagnostic programs to pick up the pieces if the system crashed while a directory was partly created, for example.

---

You can find the Unix 7th Edition manuals at [Bell Labs](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/).  Sections 2 and 3 are devoid of `mkdir(2)` and `rmdir(2)`.  You used the `mknod(2)` system call to make the directory:

> #### NAME
>
> mknod – make a directory or a special file
>
> #### SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> mknod(name, mode, addr)
> char *name;
> ```
>
> #### DESCRIPTION
>
> Mknod creates a new file whose name is the null-terminated string pointed to by name. The mode of
>   the new file (including directory and special file bits) is initialized from mode. (The protection part of
>   the mode is modified by the process’s mode mask; see umask(2)). The first block pointer of the i-node
>   is initialized from addr. For ordinary files and directories addr is normally zero. In the case of a special
>   file, addr specifies which special file.
>
> Mknod may be invoked only by the super-user.
>
> #### SEE ALSO
>
> mkdir(1), mknod(1), filsys(5)
>
> #### DIAGNOSTICS
>
> Zero is returned if the file has been made; – 1 if the file already exists or if the user is not the superuser.

The entry for `link(2)` states:

> #### DIAGNOSTICS
>
> Zero is returned when a link is made; – 1 is returned when name1 cannot be found; when name2 already
>   exists; when the directory of name2 cannot be written; when an attempt is made to link to a directory by
>   a user other than the super-user; when an attempt is made to link to a file on another file system; when a
>   file has too many links.

The entry for `unlink(2)` states:

> #### DIAGNOSTICS
>
> Zero is normally returned; – 1 indicates that the file does not exist, that its directory cannot be written,
>   or that the file contains pure procedure text that is currently in use. Write permission is not required on
>   the file itself. It is also illegal to unlink a directory (except for the super-user).

The manual page for the `ln(1)` command noted:

> It is forbidden to link to a directory or to link across file systems.

The manual page for the `mkdir(1)` command notes:

> Standard entries, '.', for the directory itself, and '..'
>   for its parent, are made automatically.

This would not be worthy of comment were it not that it was possible to create directories without those links.

---

Nowadays, the `mkdir(2)` and `rmdir(2)` system calls are standard and permit any user to create and remove directories, preserving the correct semantics.  There is no longer a need to permit users to create hard links to directories.  This is doubly true since symbolic links were introduced - they were not in 7th Edition UNIX, but were in the BSD versions of UNIX from quite early on.

---

With normal directories, the `..` entry unambiguously links back to *the* (single, solitary) parent directory.  If you have two hard links (two names) for the same directory in different directories, where does the `..` entry point?  Presumably, to the original parent directory - and presumably there is no way to get to the 'other' parent directory from the linked directory.  That's an asymmetry that can cause trouble.  Normally, if you do:

```
chdir("./subdir");
chdir("..");
```

(where `./subdir` is not a symbolic link), then you will be back in the directory you started from.  If `./subdir` is a hard link to a directory somewhere else, then you will be in a different directory from where you started after the second `chdir()`.  You'd have to show that with a pair of `stat()` calls before and after the `chdir()` operations shown.

Answer (score 6):

This is entirely because allowing hard links to directories allows for potential loops and cycles in the directory graph without adding much value.

Comment: On Mac OS X, directory hard links are supported and used to implement the Time Machine.

Comment: True, but that is independent of whether hard links in themselves are a good idea or not. Hardlinks to directories on OS X are used incredibly rarely outside of time machine, and time machine itself doesn't create links suffering from the cycles.

Comment: @Philipp: the manual page for the `link(2)` system call on MacOS X does not mention hard links to directories (for Time Machine, or anything else).  Can you point to where it is documented, or how you can see such multiply-linked directories?

Comment: @Jonathan: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432540/creating-directory-hard-links-in-macos-x, http://serverfault.com/questions/6608/what-is-the-bash-command-to-create-a-hardlink-to-a-directory-in-os-x, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80875/what-is-the-bash-command-to-create-a-hardlink-to-a-directory-in-os-x

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the possibility of getting cycles (much like with symlinks, by the way, but these are easier to detect and handle), there is a second reason I can think of.

On UNIX, there is a common assumption in use by many programs, that will assume that all directories will have a link count of 2+number of child directories. This is due to the POSIX standard directory entries '.' and '..' which link to the directory or it's parent.

(*After verification, I can say that the `root` (/) is not an exception*).

This is especially useful as a performance optimization to detect leaf directories when recursing, but many applications will exist that have found other uses for it

**Clarifying**
By allowing 'userdefined' hardlinks to directories, these `invariants` so to say will no longer hold, and any dependent applications might stop working correctly. 
The element of surprise is why you need root permissions (and some good design (re)thinking) in order to force creation of directory hardlinks

Comment: `ls -a /` shows `./` and `../` entries on every *nix I've ever looked on, and I just verified this on linux.  They are equivalent, of course - `/../../../../../../` is the same as `/./././` or just `/`.

Comment: @Dave: I don't know what you are suggesting. Of course. We were talking about the implications that has for hardlink counts on directories :)

Comment: Added clarifying comment, in case that helps

Comment: You stated that "This is due to the POSIX standard directory entries '.' and '..' which link to the directory or it's parent.  (note that the root (/) might be an exception - haven't checked).", to which I responded that, no, `/` is not an exception - it contains `.` and `..` entries just like every other directory.

Comment: @Dave. Ahh. That way! I just verified that the invariant (`2+number of subdirectories`) holds true as well :)

Comment: The only difference between root and any other directory is that both `.` and `..` refer to the same inode number, normally 2.  In other directories, they refer to different inodes.  The top (root) directory of a mounted file system also has this property when unmounted; when mounted, the kernel tricks you into thinking the `..` entry refers to the directory on which it is mounted.  This is necessary, of course, to maintain the semblance of a seamless set of directories.

Answer (score 3):

Because then the directory tree will cease to be a directory tree. One directory could have multiple parents.

Answer (score 3):

Cyclic references will break garbage collection by reference counting. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting#Dealing_with_reference_cycles) describes the problem:

> There are a variety of ways of handling the problem of detecting and collecting reference cycles. One is that a system may explicitly forbid reference cycles.

That it the way Linux does it.