# Why num of hard links of directory is more than 1 in linux?

Tags: linux, unix

I make a new dir in linux filesystem.

Why the num of hard links of this item is 2?

`drwxr-xr-x  2 zuser zuser     4096 2013-12-12 19:00 newdir/`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regarding Hard Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829001/regarding-hard-link)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An empty directory has two hard links to it, the normal entry in the parent directory, and the special directory entry `.`.

(The special directory entry `..` increases the hard link count of the parent directory.)

Comment: Could you give some reference?