# "Double dot" directory name in C?

Tags: c, macos, opendir

I'm writing a program for class, and I'm wondering about the output for a bit of code. I have some code like this:

```
DIR* dir = opendir(".");
struct dirent* reader;

while ((reader = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
{
//print the name of the path found by reader.
}
```

Now this works fine and all, but I notice that the first two listings are always:

```
.
..
//rest of files here
```

Now I'm assuming the first dot `.` is simply the name of the current directory, but what is the second double-dot for? I know `cd ..` lets you go up in the file hierarchy, but I have no clue why that is being output when reading the subdirectory names.

The reason I'm concerned is because I want to recursively go through all the files, but if I go through the `..`, the first directory name in there is `.`, which causes a loop. So how can I avoid this?

Comment: It comes from the filesystem itself -- outside of C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `..` is the parent directory. Unless you're at the filesystem root, in which case it's the same as the root directory.

Basically you want to check to see if your `dir` variable is equal to either `.` or `..`. If it is, then you skip that directory.

You could achieve this by putting that check in your `while` loop, or by filtering out those two directories from your array of directories.

Oh, make sure that you don't accidentally skip directories that start with `.`, because those are still valid directories. Make sure that the entire directory name is `.` or `..`.

Answer (score 2):

When descending into a directory structure it is important to limit the recursion -- just ignoring `.` (current directory) and `..` (parent directory) isn't enough (but it sure avoids some useless trips :-). Consider a symlink file, `foo` that links to `.` -- it would have the same effect as following `.`.

Either keep a depth count or a "seen directory" or structure (smart implementations could detect and prune cycles). Also consider using [readlink](http://linux.die.net/man/2/readlink) to inspect the target. (Note that [hardlinks to directories can be created in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80875/what-is-the-bash-command-to-create-a-hardlink-to-a-directory-in-os-x) so readlink can help, but doesn't omit the need for other guards.)

Happy coding.