# how to keep ios simulator app document path same,don't change every run xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode

As we know, in xcode6 or xcode7, app documents path will change for every run project, like below

```
/Users/jakey/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0149D36B-A46E-4326-BF59-AFEF7D2CA8B2/data/Containers/Data/Application/FDCA4FAF-4940-485B-A6B6-5CEE4C75B72F/Documents
```

but **I'm often use some tools such as navicat to access document's**. sqlite, If every time run the path changed, navicat can not connection db normally.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible.  Every time you hit Build & Run, your app is re-installed, so its container is changed.

With Xcode 7, there's a new simctl subcommand that might be helpful for you:

```
$ xcrun simctl get_app_container --help
Usage: simctl get_app_container <device> <app identifier>
```

You might want to make an alias like:

```
alias cdmyapp='cd $(xcrun simctl get_app_container booted com.mycompany.myapp)'
```

Then you can just run 'cdmyapp' from Terminal.app to enter your app's container.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this isn't possible. I imagine you would want to save files within your document directory. That is strictly within the path you've mentioned and changes.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I want to share my solution in case it helps someone in future.

You can use the ***ln(aka link)*** command to create some hard links that keep track with latest iOS simulator sandbox files.

For example, you can create a "SimulatorDB" folder on your Desktop, then run your application and get the **latest** Core Data sqlite file's path inside Sandbox, then run these 3 commands to create 3 hard links:

```
ln /{your-app-container-path}/Library/Application\ Support/App.sqlite ~/Desktop/SimulatorDB/App.sqlite
ln /{your-app-container-path}/Library/Application\ Support/App.sqlite-shm ~/Desktop/SimulatorDB/App.sqlite-shm
ln /{your-app-container-path}/Library/Application\ Support/App.sqlite-wal ~/Desktop/SimulatorDB/App.sqlite-wal
```

Then config your DB browser software to connect **~/Desktop/SimulatorDB/App.sqlite** directly.

*Notes:*
This works fine only on small amount of files, if you need to keep track on a sandbox folder with many files, the **APFS** seems not supporting this operation:
https://github.com/selkhateeb/hardlink/issues/31#issuecomment-332993819

There is some tools for create hard link on directory in macOS, but I haven't try them yet:
[What is the Unix command to create a hardlink to a directory in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80875/what-is-the-unix-command-to-create-a-hardlink-to-a-directory-in-os-x)